# Table join returns every row from entire table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

So I've got this code:

```
    select gbg.manual_grade,
                gbm.title,
                u.user_id
from gradebook_grade as gbg

join course_users as cu on gbg.course_users_pk1 = cu.pk1
join users as u on cu.users_pk1 = u.pk1
join gradebook_main as gbm on gbg.gradebook_main_pk1 = gbm.pk1
join course_main as cm on gbm.crsmain_pk1 = cm.pk1

where (cm.course_id) = 'HUMA-1301-057IN-S12013' and (u.user_id) = 'bpugh'
```

And, as that code is now, the results are perfectly what I want. The records are unique, they line up with the correct user id, and assignment. But there's one more column I need to get.

Whenever I add this line:

```
join gradebook_log as gbl on gbm.pk1 = gbl.gradebook_main_pk1
```

and modify my select statement to be

```
   select gbg.manual_grade,
                gbm.title,
                u.user_id,
                gbl.grade
```

it pulls all of the gbl.grade rows from the gradebook_log table, even though i"m trying to filter out by only the user name, but still has the column for the u.user_id, however the user names don't match up correctly with all of these extra rows that I'm now pulling.. Any idea why that is?

Comment: @Scotch `join` = `inner join` in SQL Server. The function is the same, it's just different syntax.

Comment: Looks like you need to include additional join conditions between gradebook_log and gradebook_maim, probably including the user and the course.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data/table structure?  It's pulling all rows that meet your criteria, perhaps there's another field you need in your gradebook_log join.

Comment: I've double checked the conditions and keys many times. I'm almost positive the join conditions are right. The gradebook_log table relies on primary keys of gradebook_main_k1 and users_pk1 to make the joins.

Comment: Well you just answered it then, need to incorporate 2nd join condition using the users_pk1

Comment: Well then you need to include users_pk1 in your last join

Comment: Here are the schemas for the tables that are being used. http://pastebin.com/TSvpUPd7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing join criteria on the new table, looks like it should be:

```
select gbg.manual_grade,
                gbm.title,
                u.user_id,
                gbl.grade
from gradebook_grade as gbg    
join course_users as cu on gbg.course_users_pk1 = cu.pk1
join users as u on cu.users_pk1 = u.pk1
join gradebook_main as gbm on gbg.gradebook_main_pk1 = gbm.pk1
join course_main as cm on gbm.crsmain_pk1 = cm.pk1
join gradebook_log as gbl 
      on gbm.pk1 = gbl.gradebook_main_pk1
         AND u.pk1 = gbl.users_pk1  
where (cm.course_id) = 'HUMA-1301-057IN-S12013' and (u.user_id) = 'bpugh'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
join gradebook_log as gbl 
      on gbm.pk1 = gbl.gradebook_main_pk1
and gbl.User_ForeignKey1 = u1.pkl
and gbl.CourseMain_ForeignKey2 = cm.pk1
```

**think u might want to add the foreign key to users and (coursemain if at all) and maybe give it a shot**